# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, express, postman, sendgrid

i'v been stuck for quite while now i  get this error which says UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning which is not the case i did catch error in my form controller

npm version

> "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0"

when i try to send email using postman Body :

(node:1504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

this object i get from catching the error

```
code: 403,
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Fri, 16 Apr 2021 04:16:35 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '281',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  }
}

 {
        "name":"fares",
        "email":"essayehfares@gmail.com",
        "message":"This is test This is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is testThis is test This is test" 
}
```

form controller for email

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail'); // SENDGRID_API_KEY
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    exports.contactForm = (req, res) => {
        const { email, name, message } = req.body;
        // console.log(req.body);
    
        const emailData = {
            to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
            from: email,
            subject: `Contact form - ${process.env.APP_NAME}`,
            text: `Email received from contact from \n Sender name: ${name} \n Sender email: ${email} \n Sender message: ${message}`,
            html: `
                <h4>Email received from contact form:</h4>
                <p>Sender name: ${name}</p>
                <p>Sender email: ${email}</p>
                <p>Sender message: ${message}</p>
                <hr />
                <p>This email may contain sensetive information</p>
            `
        };
    
        sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent => {
            return res.json({
                success: true
            }).catch(error=>{
                console.log('error',error)
            })
        
        });
    };
    
    exports.contactAssignmentAuthorForm = (req, res) => {
        const { authorEmail, email, name, message } = req.body;
        // console.log(req.body);
    
        let maillist = [authorEmail, process.env.EMAIL_TO];
    
        const emailData = {
            to: maillist,
            from: email,
            subject: `Someone messaged you from ${process.env.APP_NAME}`,
            text: `Email received from contact from \n Sender name: ${name} \n Sender email: ${email} \n Sender message: ${message}`,
            html: `
                <h4>Message received from:</h4>
                <p>name: ${name}</p>
                <p>Email: ${email}</p>
                <p>Message: ${message}</p>
                <hr />
                <p>This email may contain sensetive information</p>
         
            `
        };
    
        sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent => {
            return res.json({
                success: true
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
        });
    };
```

form routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { contactForm, contactAssignmentAuthorForm } = require('../controllers/form');

// validators
const { runValidation } = require('../validators');
const { contactFormValidator } = require('../validators/form');

router.post('/contact', contactFormValidator, runValidation, contactForm);
router.post('/contact-assignment-author', contactFormValidator, runValidation, contactAssignmentAuthorForm);

module.exports = router;
```

form validator

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');

exports.contactFormValidator = [
    check('name')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
        .withMessage('Name is required'),
    check('email')
        .isEmail()
        .withMessage('Must be valid email address'),
    check('message')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
        .isLength({ min: 15 })
        .withMessage('Message must be at least 20 characters long')
];
```

env file

```
NODE_ENV=development
APP_NAME=SUIVISTAGE
PORT=8000
CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
DATABASE_LOCAL='mongodb://localhost:27017/stage'
JWT_SECRET=KDJHF7823RHIU3289FJ932I2G8FG239
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.5YsBW3I7Ra2IcLLiJXfc1g.R1XYPG3SyWfyl0G1w0D5hsh5CGvECIvjYSjRcHtisDc
EMAIL_TO=faresessayeh@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by following This guide **sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification** you need to verify your sender in order for this to be completed

Answer (score 0):

You are using catch on the wrong line, `res.json` doesn't require `catch` block. attach catch block to `sendgrid.then` method like below

```
    sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent => {
        return res.json({
            success: true
        })
    }).catch(error=>{
       console.log('error',error)
    })
```

Also, don't post your API keys like this in public, they are not needed to understand your code.

Comment: still did not work same issue , is there any configuration in sendgrid i should i care about settings -> Api Keys -> i created one and i'v copied it and that's it

Comment: There are two places where you have to do the same thing (catch block), did you updated both places (i.e. in `contactAssignmentAuthorForm` & `contactForm` function?

Comment: i just updated the code after quite the research i think they updated the way authentification it need some configuration [link]https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/

Comment: I reviewed and it seems first you have to create the sender's identity and API key and also add a list of specific IP addresses to the list to be able to send email successfully. You can log the error response body using `error.response.body` to see an error in detail.